# Shared folder between two sites?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008

Just looking for some advice..

I have two websites on IIS7 which are seperate websites but are the same website company. One manages the site (CRM) and the other is the actual website.

On the CRM they add products with images which are saved within the CRM's ~/productImages/ folder. I know I can't access the images via the website because of permissions so I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions?

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each website should have a virtual folder pointing to the same physical folder, where the shared images are stored.

Alternatively you can make the actual website's virtual image folder point to the physical location of the CRM image folder.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a Virtual Directory on the second Web Site, which you can have separate permissions on. That way, you can enable access from the second web site.